# textToSpeech.synthetizeToFile creates a corrupted file?

Tags: android, file, text-to-speech, corrupt

```
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
private void saveAudio(String text)
{
    HashMap<String, String> myHashRender = new HashMap();
    String textToConvert = text;
    String destinationFileName = "/sdcard/audio.wav";
    myHashRender.put(TextToSpeech.Engine.KEY_PARAM_UTTERANCE_ID, textToConvert);
    tts.synthesizeToFile(textToConvert, myHashRender, destinationFileName);
}
```

This is my function that should save the audio into a file. The method synthesizeToFile returns 0, which means SUCCESS, and creates the file, but it's corrupted, it doesn't play in any Media Player. I use the deprecated version of the method because my version is 16. I also have

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

What is wrong with this code?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Are you using a progress listener or utterance completed listener to confirm the file has completed writing, before attempting to play/listen to it?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it created empty audio file. But when I commented the last row in next code snippet it started write the file correctly:

```
        String sLcl = screen7thTextFileUri.getPath();
        iLcl=sLcl.lastIndexOf(File.separator);
        sLcl=sLcl.substring(0,iLcl);
        String textLcl = getTypedText();
        mTts.synthesizeToFile(textLcl, null, new File(sLcl+"/test.wav"),"0");
        mTts.speak(textLcl , TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
```